# How to set column width based on content in kendo ui grid angular 2?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

Am using angualr 2 kengo ui grid components to display the table data. We want to set the column width based on longest cell value for each columns. Is there any config property to set it our or any other solution?.

Thanks for the support

Answer (score -1):

Use html width property for width in percentage.

Comment: Yeah I can use. But we need to set based on content length.

Comment: If i set it in percentage, text will get wrap to next line